# php problem for view images from blob mysql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, blob

I had created 2 PHP files, 1 is uploading images to MySql database and 1 is display images from MySql. The problem is that when I submit the images contain size > 730 KiB to MySql Blob then the display page can't view that images from Blob Type(But the display page can view only image size <= 730 KiB from Blob MySql).

This is my PHP Upload File(upload_donation.php)

```
                       <?php 
                        $fileSize =  $_FILES['file']['size'];
                         if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $fileSize > 5000000) {
                          echo "Your image is too large, Please resize it!!!"; 
                          ?>
                          <div> <a href="https://dkshoescollection.com/donation-submit-template/">&#8592;  Go Back</a> </div>
                          <?php
                          die();
                         }

                      else if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $fileSize <= 5000000){
                        $file = ($_FILES['file']);
                        //print_r($file);
                        // print_r($_FILES['file']);

                      $fileName =  $_FILES['file']['name'];
                      // $fileSize =  $_FILES['file']['size'];
                      $fileTmpName =  $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
                      $fileError =  $_FILES['file']['error'];
                      $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];

                      $imgData = file_get_contents($fileTmpName);


                      $imageProperties = getimageSize($fileTmpName);
                    

                      $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
                      $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

                      $allowed = array('jpg','jpeg','png');

                      if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {
                           if ($fileError === 0) {
                               if ($fileSize <= 6000000) {
                                   $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt;
                                   $fileDestination = 'wp-content/themes/flatsome/donation_images/'.$fileNameNew;
                                   move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);

                                    $data = array(
                                    'products_category' => $_POST['products_category'],
                                    'proname' => $_POST['proname'],
                                    'mime' => $imageProperties['mime'],
                                    'image_name' => $fileNameNew,
                                    'image' => $imgData,
                                    'products_size' => $_POST['products_size'],
                                    'quality' => $_POST['quality'],
                                    'proprice' => $_POST['proprice'],
                                    'donate_to' => $_POST['donate_to'],
                                    'donorname' => $_POST['donorname'],
                                    'donorphone' => $_POST['donorphone'],
                                    'donate_date' => $_POST['donate_date']

                                  );
                                  $table_name = 'wp_donation_list';

                                  $result = $wpdb -> insert($table_name, $data, $format=null);

                                  
                                  if ($result ==1){
                                      echo "Your donation was saved!"; 
                                      ?>
                                      
                                      <div> <a href="https://dkshoescollection.com/view-donations-list/">&#8592;  Go To Donations List Now</a> </div>
                                      <?php
                             
                                      

                                       
                                  }else{
                                    echo "<script>alert('Your donation unable to save!');</script>";?>
                                     <div> <a href="https://dkshoescollection.com/donation-submit-template/">&#8592;  Go Back</a> </div>
                                     <?php
                                  }     

                                   
                                   ?>
           
                                  <?php

                               } else{
                                  echo "Your file is too large!";?>
                                  <div> <a href="https://dkshoescollection.com/donation-submit-template/">&#8592;  Go Back</a> </div>
                                  <?php
                               }
                           }else {
                              echo "There was an error uploading your file!";
                              ?>
                                  <div> <a href="https://dkshoescollection.com/donation-submit-template/">&#8592;  Go Back</a> </div>
                                  <?php
                           }
                              }else {
                           echo "You cannot upload files of this types!";
                          ?>
                                  <div> <a href="https://dkshoescollection.com/donation-submit-template/">&#8592;  Go Back</a> </div>
                                  <?php
                                }    
 
                               }     
                ?>
```

And This is my PHP Display File(view_donations_template.php).

```
        <table class= "table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                     <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Image</th>
                    <th>Size</th>
                    <th>Quality</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>To</th>
                    <th>Donor</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
             
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <?php
                $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","","");
                $db = mysqli_select_db($connection ,'');

                $query = "select * from `wp_donation_list`";
                $query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run)) 
                {
                 ?> 
                 <tr>
                    <td> <?php echo $row['id']?></td>
                    <td> <?php echo $row['products_category']?></td>
                    <td> <?php echo $row['proname']?></td>
                    <td> <?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['image']).'" alt="Image";>';?></td>
                    <td> <?php echo $row['products_size']?></td>
                    <td> <?php echo $row['quality']?></td>
                    <td> <?php echo $row['proprice']?></td>
                    <td> <?php echo $row['donate_to']?></td>
                    <td> <?php echo $row['donorname']?></td>
                    <td> <?php echo $row['donorphone']?></td>
                    <td> <?php echo $row['donate_date']?></td>
                    <td> <?php echo $row['status']?></td>  
                 </tr>
                 <?php
                }
                ?>
           
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: We're not going to be able to fix anything for you from just a brief description. Please provide relevant code, debugging information etc. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more guidance. Thanks.

Comment: P.S. What debugging have you done? Displaying an image isn't normally an issue just because of size. Are you certain the image data is actually being saved in the database to begin with? Failing to upload due to size is a much more likely cause. You need to do some basic tests and checks to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Hi sir, for me 100% uploaded successfully. But when display was a problem as I told above( Images size < 730 KiB will displayed , but size > 730 KiB will not).

Comment: It seems strange, and quite unlikely. But either way we cannot help you just from your words. As I said we need enough code and data to be able to understand/reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi sir, I just upload my php files, Please help to check it. Thanks you.

Comment: It looks like your using the wrong type of blob. Change the column type from `BLOB` to `LONGBLOB`, so you can store more data into the column. Did you try?

Comment: Yes, I actually use LONGBLOB, Because BLOB can't store large file. As I told you that no problems on uploading, But error when displaying. And I want to let's you know that I created those files on package flatsome(It's work normally out of package flatsome).

Comment: Did you check if the database content is larger than 730 Kb? If not, it could be some memory/post limit set in your php.ini.

Comment: Also try to store the data base64 encoded in to the database, and decode it on parsing. It could be an encoding problem/setting of your database table/column.

Comment: Hi sir, Now I decided to not using BLOB. Now I'm uploading by moving each images to server directory and pull it to show on page by images path. But the problem is it's take so long time for uploading each image(For 3MiB image, It's take around 15sec to 20sec). Noted: My internet speed was good.